# How to make tabs without toolbar

Tags: android

I have made two tabs by example but there is a toolbar too. How can i erase it? Look at my MainActivity.java and activity_main.xml

```
package com.example.andrew.tabstest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Declaring Your View and Variables

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    CharSequence Titles[] = {"Home", "Events"};
    int Numboftabs = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);

        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.tabsScrollColor);
            }
        });

        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    }

}
```

My layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />

    <com.example.andrew.tabstest.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@color/сolorPrimary"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>



</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried to cut this part but the area of toolbar just become red and not erased.

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: The example project actually has the tabs embedded in the toolbar, meaning if you remove the toolbar the tabs will have to go as well.

Comment: Do you remove toolbar from xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code in your onCreate method

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
if(bar != null) {
    bar.hide();
 }
```

The check for null is because not every activity may have an actionbar, so to be on the safe side. You may skip it and just use the concise

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

The default theme applies an ActionBar, and hence this is why you are getting an ActionBar even if you aren't applying a custom toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` from your activity tag or you can modify it as :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need toolbar just remove the following code:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />
```

from layout and From MainActivity remove

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Also you can use App theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

in your style.xml